# Delimited files in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Are there any built in functions to read or write comma delimited files?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, TextFieldParser.  The how-to MSDN article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx).

Comment: Ive never seen this one - interesting.

Comment: Ahhhh, the VisualBasic specific namespace! I actually don't hold any personal grudge against it but I recently read a paper some place which showed both sides: the lovers and the haters - I guess it's a matter of utility and acceptance. Nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built in, unless you count interop to ODBC or legacy ADO. I recommend the ["fast CSV reader"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) on codeproject; robust and fast. I've use it countless times.

It sounds tempting to think "just split on comma", but it is a or more subtle than that; multiline, escaped, the infamous comma/period swapping in some EU... Using a library is a good call here.

Comment: You don't need "interop to legacy ADO". You can use ADO.NET with the ODBC CSV provider. I'd still go with something with less overhead, though.